# How to limit GEOjson data to specific area?

Tags: shapefile, geojson

I am currently working with a shapefile from the United States Drought Monitor that countains all drought data from all of the states in the US. I am converting it to geojson with ogr2ogr and would like to filter the geojson output so that it only contains data within the bounds of California. How can I do this?

I am wondering if there are optional arguments I can pass in to something like `ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON drought.json  USDM_20140617.shp`

Or would I only be able to limit the results by doing a join between shapefiles (for example, a join with a shapefile that contained data for California's boundaries)?

Shapefiles are [here](http://droughtmonitor.unl.edu/MapsAndData/GISData.aspx)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two alternatives. The first one is to use the -clipsrc parameter.

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" test.shp world_boundaries_m.shp -clipsrc "POLYGON (( 1308807.8548639829 2728968.1094570993, 823671.391414903 169260.41200850534, 3897264.203215087 209607.73328746122, 2782801.7002406875 2976763.0370215555, 1308807.8548639829 2728968.1094570993 ))"
```

However, this option clips the geometries with the polygon and you may prefer to select features as they are. In this case the -sql parameter with SQLite dialect is extremely powerful.

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" test2.shp world_boundaries_m.shp -dialect sqlite -sql "select * from world_boundaries_m where ST_Intersects (geometry,geomfromtext('POLYGON (( 1308807.8548639829 2728968.1094570993, 823671.391414903 169260.41200850534, 3897264.203215087 209607.73328746122, 2782801.7002406875 2976763.0370215555, 1308807.8548639829 2728968.1094570993 ))'))"
```

Depending on your data you may need to adjust the polygon and add SRID after the WKT polygon but the query above worked for me with my test data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there a way of doing SQL-style joins between two GeoJSON files (ex. a left or inner join) outputting a new .json file as the result of the join?

Comment: I would have a try with GDAL VRT file http://www.gdal.org/drv_vrt.html. Create a VRT that publishes your two files as one datasource with two layers and query that with ogr2ogr.